# How do I return a 2D array by summing each value in a 3D array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I'm working with a 3D list in Python. I'm trying to sum each value along the z-axis.
my 3D list:

```
a=[[[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],
  [[21,22,23],[24,25,26],[27,28,29]],
  [[31,32,33],[34,35,36],[37,38,39]]]
```

However im a bit lost as :

```
print(a[:][0][0])
print(a[0][:][0])
print(a[0][0][:])
```

all return `[31,32,33]`

I have the solution :

```
for i in range(len(a[0])):
   for j in range(len(a[0][0])):
      b[i][j]=sum([a[k][i][j] for k in range(len(a))])
```

But this seem clunky so im hoping there is a more pythonic way

To clarify the desired result would be: `[[63, 66, 69], [72, 75, 78], [81, 84, 87]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. that works, but I found another cleaner solution that requires importing numpy.

```
a=[[[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],
 [[21,22,23],[24,25,26],[27,28,29]],
 [[31,32,33],[34,35,36],[37,38,39]]]

print(numpy.sum(a, axis=0))
# prints [[63 66 69] [72 75 78] [81 84 87]]
```

which can be converted back to a list with:

```
numpy.sum(a, axis=0).tolist()
```

Minor note this is about 30% faster then the nested for loops from the question even after you convert back to list.
I also tried to test Aphton's answer but that was written for python 2.7 and changes xrange to range cases incorrect results. I also found it was about 50% slower then the nested for loops